# Is there a way to exclude a certain field in a sub-collection of a mongo object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For instance if I want to not return phone numbers

Given an object

```
{ who: [ { name: "Joe", phone: "555-555-5555" } ], what: "eat"}
```

Can I do a query that excludes the phone number from who?  i.e. something akin to this? (but this query does not work since I can't manipulate the projection of the who).

```
find({​}{who.phone:0}).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just need to quote your dotted key (and add a missing comma):

```js
find({​}, {'who.phone': 0}).limit(10)
```

Comment: Adding a link to the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/